# How to format a formula in Microsoft Excel to be in percentage format DIRECTLY in the CSV source file

Tags: excel, csv

The problem:

For example, my CSV data is like so: `['=B3/B5']` which displays `0.1` in my Excel sheet but I need it to produce `10%`.

I need to be able to fix this from the CSV source data because I'm exporting a CSV file from my website so that means no excel formatting to percentages as I need it to work out of the box for users.

Preferably the solution should be able to support Excel 2007. Google Sheets has a `=to_percent(B3/B5)` function which works well but I need the equivalent for Excel 2007.

I had a look at this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string

But doesn't seem to directly address the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `=B3/B5*100&"%"`

Note that this will not be saved as a number (ex. `22.1%`) rather as text, because you can't use number formats in a CSV file.